# Updating a mercurial webserver

Tags: mercurial

I have a server running mercuial 1.7.2 and want to upgrade to the newest version.  What is the best way to go about deploying a new version?  Do I need to recopy the templates folder and mercurial folder for python?

Comment: You should provide information about your server to begin with. What is your OS ? How do you installed Mercurial the first time ? etc... Secondly, what are you calling the 'templates folder' abd the 'mercurial folder for python' ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally speaking, you can simply replace your installed Mercurial with a new version and have it work.

- old CGI and WSGI scripts are all forward-compatible and you don't need to update them
- you shouldn't need to update config files
- new Mercurial versions will read and write old repositories without issue

The only thing you need to worry about is if you've modified the **stock web templates**, in which case you'll want to back them up and restore them.

See this page for other notes on upgrading:

https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/UpgradingMercurial

Comment: Thank you.  Also, I did not realize that the mercurial-server tag was strictly for ssh.  I have been fighting with someone untagging this and another mercurial question with that tag.  If he would have explained it and not just untagged I would have understood.